# Laravel 5 database query retrieve first table data but not in other table

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

Here I give some mysql sample code. I want to write this code in Laravel 5.
E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employees.id NOT IN(SELECT
    team_employees.employee_id
    FROM team_employees)
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code that you have tried ? Show us your efforts, so that we can help you faster. There are least chances of help for you without the code.

Comment: I have added mysql query and what i want to do is write in laravel style.

Comment: You can try with a raw query Model::whereNotIn(\DB::raw('SELECT team_employees....'))->get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all finally i found bellow answer. This was pretty cool and very easy. Thanks for all for commenting.......
I think bellow code will help you........

```
 > DB::table('employees')
    >          ->select(['employees.id', 'employees.code', 'employees.full_name'])
    >          ->whereNotExists(function ($query) use ($request) {
    >                 $query->select(['team_employees.employee_id'])
    >                       ->from('team_employees')
    >                       ->whereRaw('team_employees.employee_id = employees.id')
    >                       ->where('team_employees.team_id', $request['team_id']);
    >                 });
```

> **$request** is a parameter which send by client side.....